# My faster rcnn model keeps failing at a certain step and the learning curve does not change

Tags: tensorflow

latest step: I1211 07:28:47.730407 14064 model_lib_v2.py:648] Step 7500 per-step time 2.311s loss=0.136

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference__dist_train_step_61032]

Function call stack:
_dist_train_step -> _dist_train_step

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3688  visit address.
There it says that negative values should be eliminated as a solution. @carlosfab offers the right solution.